# How to properly use SelectListItem for HTML.DropDownList instead of SelectList?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, ienumerable

I've been digging through other posts trying to figure out how to go from using a `SelectList` in my controller to fill an `@Html.DropDownList` in my View to instead use what seems to be the commonly suggested `SelectListItem`, but I'm completely lost?

I have a main `INV_Assets` model that when I go to the Edit View, I include Drop Down Lists for other Model Properties (Location, Manufacturer, Model, Status, Type, Vendor, etc.) My current code below adequately fills the lists and allows me on `Edit()` to change the chosen entity value to any other value stored in that relevant table.

**CURRENT CODE**:

*Controller*:

```
// GET: INV_Assets/Edit/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            INV_Assets iNV_Assets = await db.INV_Assets.FindAsync(id);
            if (iNV_Assets == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            ViewBag.Location_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Locations, "Id", "location_dept", iNV_Assets.Location_Id);
            ViewBag.Manufacturer_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Manufacturers, "Id", "manufacturer_description", iNV_Assets.Manufacturer_Id);
            ViewBag.Model_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Models, "Id", "model_description", iNV_Assets.Model_Id);
            ViewBag.Status_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Statuses, "Id", "status_description", iNV_Assets.Status_Id);
            ViewBag.Type_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Types, "Id", "type_description", iNV_Assets.Type_Id);
            ViewBag.Vendor_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Vendors, "Id", "vendor_name", iNV_Assets.Vendor_Id);
            return View(iNV_Assets);
        }

        // POST: INV_Assets/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Model_Id,Manufacturer_Id,Type_Id,Location_Id,Vendor_Id,Status_Id,ip_address,mac_address,note,owner,cost,po_number,description,invoice_number,serial_number,asset_tag_number,acquired_date,disposed_date,created_date,created_by,modified_date,modified_by")] INV_Assets iNV_Assets)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(iNV_Assets).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.Location_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Locations, "Id", "location_dept", iNV_Assets.Location_Id);
            ViewBag.Manufacturer_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Manufacturers, "Id", "manufacturer_description", iNV_Assets.Manufacturer_Id);
            ViewBag.Model_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Models, "Id", "model_description", iNV_Assets.Model_Id);
            ViewBag.Status_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Statuses, "Id", "status_description", iNV_Assets.Status_Id);
            ViewBag.Type_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Types, "Id", "type_description", iNV_Assets.Type_Id);
            ViewBag.Vendor_Id = new SelectList(db.INV_Vendors, "Id", "vendor_name", iNV_Assets.Vendor_Id);
            return View(iNV_Assets);
        }
```

*View - Just [Locations] for example*:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Location_Id, "Location_Id", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })*@
            <span class="control-label col-md-2">Location:</span>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Location_Id", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location_Id, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I'm trying to do now is add a value to each list stating "Add New", which I want to allow users to click on and have a (partial view?) popup for them to immediately add a new relevant record (Ex. New [Location] of "Warehouse 2") and then be able to choose that from the [Locations] list for the particular Asset being Edited.

Can anyone walk me through this?

A lot of the suggestions are to add a `SelectList` or `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` to my relevant Model properties, but from there I am lost on what to tweak in my controller/view? Currently I am using Code-First Migrations with an `InventoryTrackerContext.cs` inside my `DAL` folder for the project.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing two very different aspects of this. First, `Html.DropDownList` only requires an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. Passing a full `SelectList` object satisfies this parameter merely because a `SelectList` *is* an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. The advice to not use `SelectList` is simply to save yourself the work of having to construct a full `SelectList` object (and remembering to do things like set the `selectedValue` to the right item), when Razor will handle this for you. Whether you use `SelectList` or `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` has no bearing on the remainder of your question.

As far as adding items to an existing drop down list goes, you have to use JavaScript for that. At a basic level, it's as simple as just just selecting the `select` element in the DOM and appending a new `option` node.

Comment: Is it not possible to add the new option via the Controller instead of JS/jQuery?

Comment: Not without reloading the entire page. Since the user is adding new choices through a popup, you have to either reload the entire page to refresh the choices from the controller or use JS to insert the newly added choice dynamically.